# Embedded Tomcat Cluster

Tags: java, embedded-systems, cluster, tomcat

Can someone please explain with an example how an Embedded Tomcat Cluster works. Would a load balancer be necessary?

Since we're using embedded tomcat, how would two separate jar files (each a standalone web application with their own embedded tomcat instance) know where eachother are and let eachother know their status, etc?

Here is the code I have so far which is just a regular embedded tomcat without any clustering which would formulate one of the jar files mentioned above:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  throws LifecycleException, InterruptedException, ServletException {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    tomcat.setPort(8080);

    Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());

    Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "hello", new HttpServlet() {
      protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {
        Writer w = resp.getWriter();
        w.write("Hello, World!");
        w.flush();
      }
    });
    ctx.addServletMapping("/*", "hello");

    tomcat.start();
    tomcat.getServer().await();
  }

}
```

Source: [java dzone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedded-tomcat-minimal)

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Should I be using a different site for this question?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it and theres just about nothing on Google about it. I therefore have nothing to share except failed google searches.

Comment: since you have sufficient reputation, I would consider asking for advice in [chat] (Whiteboard room)

Comment: Considering this kind of information is rare on the web, would it not be wise to have it here?

Comment: considering that we don't yet know whether it's indeed rare or not (single failed web search doesn't qualify sorry) I can only repeat prior advice to discuss this in chat

Comment: Sorry, it was several hours of searching. My fault for not mentioning

Comment: Are you familiar with Tomcat clustering as such? Basically, you configure Tomcat so that it can send/receive messages to/from other Tomcats. Typically, they discover the existence of other nodes and communicate via TCP/IP. So, in the case of *embedded* Tomcat.

Comment: @DariusX. Thank you for the above. Do you think you would be able to use your knowledge of tomcat clustering in general to build an example using the API (which seems to be for the regular tomcat, not embedded tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/introduction.html) by any remote chance?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tomcat-8 (we use 7). In your case, do you configure Tomcat using server.xml, or something similar? If there's a API to set up the configuration, I'm not familiar with it. Are you using JMX for this? How do you configure it today, without the clustering? Where do you configure the "Engine" or the "Host"? As a 'child' to one of these, you will need to configure a cluster. The equivalent of: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

Comment: @DariusX. Thank you for the above. I don't use any server.xml because it's embedded tomcat so I just use plain java. This is what I've found so far: http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedded-tomcat-minimal - I'm just trying to extend on that example so that I can use it in a cluster.

Comment: In the Javadocs, I see there's a SimpleTcpCluster class. So, I assume you can instantiate one, and use addChild() on the Engine. Basically, you would be making calls to create the config in Java. 
BTW, you will still need something outside to do the load-balancing. I don't know how that would work for an embedded Tomcat. We use Apache to load-balance.

Comment: Wouldn't load balancing be the easy part, simply using round robin to distribute requests to nodes in the cluster? I thought the cluster nodes themselves had to be intelligent about their surroundings (affinity, state, etc), I didn't think that the load balancer took that responsibility?